# UHF RFID Reader with Raspberry Pi

Tags: python, serial, rfid

I have a RFID Reader like the one posted on this link:
http://www.ebay.com/itm/EPC-Gen2-UHF-Integrative-5-7-Meters-Long-Range-RFID-Reader-with-free-SDK-/171473207602

It has RS232, RS485 and Weigand interfaces. I tried interfacing it using a Prolific USB to Serial Converter and a RS232 to TTL logic level shifter with MAX3232 CSE in it but with no luck of getting a data.

How can I attach this reader to the Pi and how can I interface this? What are the recommended Python libraries that I could use? Thank you very much!

Comment: Where did you connect the output of your TTL logic level shifter?

Comment: I connected it to the RX/TX GPIO pins of the Pi. I powered it using the 3.3v pin of the Pi also.

Comment: You should test that the Pi tx and rx are working like you think.  Connect the Pi tx/rx lines to eachother and run your software.  Every character you transmit you should receive on the pi

Comment: You mean I should just connect the two pins with each other and send then receive? How can I do that with Python? I'm sorry for being so noob.